# Haven't driven my car in over a year, how to get it back up and running again?

Tags: battery, long-term-storage

Since the start of the pandemic lockdowns and with everybody working from home, I haven't had a reason to use my car and it slipped my mind to take it out every once in a while.  So, now the car obviously won't start.  Evidently the battery still has a small amount of charge, enough to light some diagnostic lights and the cabin lights but certainly not nearly enough to start the car.  The diagnostic lights that currently come on are the check engine, oil, battery, tire pressure lights.  The fuel gauge shows the tank half full.  (Last oil change was approximately 1 week before the lockdowns started, so obviously that's overdue as well.)

So now, since I'm guessing I'll probably need to drive somewhere to get a vaccination soon, I'm trying to figure out how to get the car serviced.  I'm not at all sure whether it could be possible to call AAA or something like that, and get a jump start to at least get me to a mechanic - or whether it's been long enough that I should just go directly to calling a tow service.

The car is a 2009 Toyota Corolla, and it's been in an underground garage in Los Angeles.

(Sorry if this is too basic a question for this site, or if there's a good duplicate.  The closest thing I saw was from a question posted just a few months into the pandemic period.  The other questions I saw also seemed to be from the point of the view of the questioner having equipment to do a jump start or other basic things themselves, which in my case I don't have.)

Comment: OK, the question this is marked as duplicating is the one I was mentioning in the text, where I was not at all sure whether an answer good for a few months would still be valid for a bit over a year.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just jump it for starters... If it was running fine before it shouldn't have any real reason not to be running fine now (other than Not being able to start due to dead battery) and until the engine is able to start and run for a little there's no way to really know if anything is wrong just listen for funny sounds and let it idle for a bit so the computer can run through some of it's diagnostics. As for the check engine light coming on it should always come on when the key is turned to let you know it's working so there's probably not even a code set and once jumped and running should go out immediately.